# Can I write parts of the Google App Engine code in Java, other parts in Python?

Tags: java, python, google-app-engine

Google App Engine supports both Python and Java application development.

Can I have both in the same application?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> **Can I run Java and Python code in the same app?**
>
> Each version of the app must specify a runtime language and it is possible to have version x of your app running Java, while version y is running Python. It would also be possible to use Jython.

Source: [Google App Engine for Java FAQ](http://code.google.com/appengine/kb/java.html#pythonandjava)

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, there are two ways:

- Write **another app** in java, publish it as a web services and call it from python (but that's not what you are looking for)
- Make a **java application** but write it in [jython](http://www.jython.org/). Then your app will be written in python, it will run on JVM, and calls to java API are trivial.

Answer (score 3):

Just to have an updated answer for this question,

From this [answer](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-appengine/1228g7-qXZY/_ubjgHlE2_wJ) on GAE google groups, it looks like it is possible to have different modules in different languages.