# Is it possible to use Python with Go

Tags: python, google-app-engine, go

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mixing python with a faster language for optimization in GAE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6807119/mixing-python-with-a-faster-language-for-optimization-in-gae)

I wounder if you can use python with Go, I have just introduced myself to Go (by mistake lol, although that it exists long time ago) to Go, it feels like python, I like it, but I'm not planning to learn it because python satisfies me, I'm just wondering, is it possible to create an app on google app engine using python sdk and Go for some tasks?

I already know that they have a totally different for go

EDIT

I think i have just asked a stupid question because I have just found out that you have to compile Go!

anyway I'll keep the question for today maybe I'll have a good answer that I'm not expecting.

Comment: beware that go support on appengine is "experimental" - for a while last month it wasn't possible to add new apps, for example (i ended up rewriting an application in python to work round this).

Comment: See my answer to the other question.

Comment: @andrew cooke thanks man, you know what I'll wait for the official sdk before i work with Go

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use different languages in the same app -- however, each one in a different version. They will have access to the same datastore and memcache, however CRON and (I think) tasks will only work for the active version (because they target the main version url using a relative path). You would have to "talk" between versions using HTTP. You can also have the main app in Python and a Go or Java backend, etc.

Go is compiled, but the Go SDK do all the work for you, re-compiling the app each time you change your code. It is pretty neat and fun to try Go this way.

Comment: ok I'll go for Go, but not the experimental SDK, I'll wait for the official SDK, did they announce the release date of the official sdk or we just have to wait?

Comment: They normally don't announce dates. So no ETA yet, afaik.

Comment: +1 Nice, I was actually wondering if it was possible to use a different lang in different app version. I've just been a bit lazy to actually `try` it. Thanks =)

Comment: Since 30th of March, 2011 it is possible to specify app version in target attribute of cron.yaml file - see http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron.html#About_cron_yaml