# Using both java and python modules in Google AppEngine

Tags: java, python, google-app-engine

It seems that it's possible to have both Java and Python modules in the same gae App - see the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18382955/using-both-java-and-python-with-the-new-module-feature-on-appengine). Various browsing and searching indicates that not only is it possible, but that it's been done, but I can't find any details.

I think I understand how to do it, but I can't work out how to use the Java and Python SDKs together to do the development. They seem to be completely different. Does anyone know how to do this?

(Why do I want to do this?  I've got a reasonable front end developed in Python, which I really don't want to have to re-implement, but the heavy numeric calculations are just too slow. I'm seeing huge performance gains, as expected, from re-implementing the calculation engine in Java. All I need to do now is to hook it in instead of the current Python implementation ...)

Comment: Have you checked if numpy (which is supported) improves your numeric calculations?

Comment: As to running both, you should read through modules https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/

Comment: I've read both the Python and Java documentation on modules. Neither mentions the other. And I can't find anything anywhere that discusses using the SDK across languages, which is what this question is about.

Comment: Each module can be a different language.

Comment: A quick search on SO has some discussion on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18382955/using-both-java-and-python-with-the-new-module-feature-on-appengine

Comment: Also this SO talks about it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342059/can-i-write-parts-of-the-google-app-engine-code-in-java-other-parts-in-python  but relies on version as it predates modules.  There some quite significant commercial products out there doing it.

Comment: Yes @TimHoffman, that first question is the one I referred to. But neither of these has any hints about how to go about it, and especially whether it's possible to get the two development servers in the SDKs to work together.

Comment: I sugegst you go to the google group  There are a number of threads on using modules with multiple languages there, and people who are doing it but they don't visit SO.  Running both langauages concurrently in dev may be problematic but at least one poster has said they are doing it.