# Access Google Cloud Datastore from another app/project

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-datastore

We got a couple millions data in the current GAE project using Google Cloud store. Mostly GPS point information. We want to be able to use all these GPS points in another demo instance, which is hosted in another GAE instance. Anyway we can do it?

Using Golang + Google App Engine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [Google Cloud Datastore API](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/getstarted/start_java/) that you can use to access your Datastore data from any other deployment, including a different App Engine app. It's not available in Go, so you will have to [mix in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342059/can-i-write-parts-of-the-google-app-engine-code-in-java-other-parts-in-python) some Python or Java.